# how can we finds system having JVM or not by using C#.net?

Tags: c#

how to know, whether that system has installed the JAVA or Not?

Answer (score 1):

I assume using C#/.net you can check the registry easily. For a Sun JRE you can check that the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
```

exists. See [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/install/jdk/install-windows.html) for more info. Note particularly that this *doesn't* work for the JDK, only the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

The command line

```
java -version
```

will give you the currently installed java version. So in C#

```
Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-version";
 p.Start();
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Will give you the version. For some reason on my box it's coming out on the standard error stream?